# Where can I download the source code of "Google Play Music" for android4.1?

Tags: android

I am looking for **Google Play Music** app's source code....But I found the *android source code of "**Music.git**"* was not what I want. The "Google Play Music" app in pad can `show a scrolling album pictures` that is what effect I want.

Can anyone tell me or give me some tips?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That source code is not open-source.  Furthermore, it is likely they have obfusciated the release APK, so you would not decompile it.

Maybe you are looking for a this control?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer and tips. But I wanna that 3D scrolling effect with so many album pictures. Do you have any some relative experience? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Google Play Music is a proprietary closed source app. Its source code is not available.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and tips. But I wanna that 3D scrolling effect with so many album pictures. Do you have any some relative experience? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's tons of posts on this topic:

[Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

I don't know how the album art is stored though.